# How many callbacks are there for each instance of a duplex service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current.aspx) says:

> Use the Current property to obtain the execution and message context
>   for the current method.

After [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx), I realized that every service method could create a new instance of callback: I suppose that this is due to the fact that any method of service can be invoked from a different client, so if a method is invoked by a client already connected, then it returns the same instance of the callback, whereas if it is invoked from a new client, then creates a new instance of the service and returned to the callback will be different.
Is it correct?

In [another example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx), however, sessions are managed manually, meaning that the client must explicitly subscribe to the service: each subscription by a new client occurs in a new service instance, then the callback is unique for a given client.
Is it correct?

And if the service was of singleton type, there would be a single instance of the service to all clients: in this case, if I wanted to apply the publish-subscribe pattern, how many callback instances would be created?